# Replacement for XMarks?

Tags: web-browser, synchronization, bookmark

I've been using XMarks for a decade, but just received a notification from LastPass that as of May 1, they're discontinuing the service. I'm a web developer, and I rely on bookmarks being synced between devices and browsers.

I know that Chrome and Firefox each have their own syncing service across devices, but I need a service that will sync one set of bookmarks across all browsers on all devices.

I'm not a fan of del.icio.us, or any social service. Are there any alternatives? I'm fine with having to install a plugin on all my browsers and devices.

ETA that I want something that will sync my current bookmark bar folders (i.e. enhance the native browser bookmarks, not redesign the bookmark experience). I do *not* want a "manager" that requires me to open a separate app, or go to a website, to access my bookmarks.

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm not seeing any other answers, I'll answer my own question in case anyone else is looking for the same thing I was.

A colleague recommended Everhelper's [Eversync](https://www.everhelper.me/synchronizer.php) to me. It seems to behave pretty much the same way XMarks did; it keeps my existing bookmarks in sync across browsers and machines without requiring me to visit a website to view or edit said bookmarks.

I've only been using it a few weeks, but it seems to be stable.

Comment: For me, now, Eversync is usable **only** in Opera - Chrome's extension install hangs with (strange) error "Image decode failed", FF (last on W10) can't connect with addons-site

Comment: Hmm. I use it in Chrome and FF on several machines and had no problems with the install. One of my machines is on W7, the other is on W10.

Comment: Yes, **now** it have restored your functionality (Chrome and access to FF's addons-site - last is funny due to previous error-message on connect). But anyway far away from XMarks (and FF-extension in more buggy, than others)

Answer (score -1):

I got tired of Xmarks a while ago and moved to Bookmark OS (https://bookmarkos.com) which I would recommend. I doesn't do direct syncing but is a website so it works on all browsers and mobile devices. The UI is much better than browser managers anyways in my opinion.

Comment: "I do not want a manager.....or go ti a website". Does this not need that? (Have not used it, am generally asking).

Comment: Thanks, but I specifically noted that I do *not* want a website, and *do* want direct syncing.