# Is there any cross-platform browser bookmark syncing plugin reminiscent of xmarks.com?

Tags: web-browser, chrome, firefox, synchronization, bookmark

A number of years ago there was a cross-platform bookmark plugin called xmarks.com. It was great, but it was subsequently shut down and since then, I've been unable to find anything comparable.

What I'm looking for is some sort of bookmark manager that can sync bookmarks added on one browser/machine with the bookmarks I might have on another different browser. These are the desired features:

- Support for all browsers, particularly Firefox and Chrome
- Cross platform, particularly Windows and Linux, and ideally, Android

Does such a plugin/software exist?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate, actually:
https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/49429/replacement-for-xmarks

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Floccus.](https://floccus.org)

It's a browser extension so it supports all browsers and there is a companion app for Android:

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.handmadeideas.floccus
- https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.handmadeideas.floccus/

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a direct replacement, but it's worth knowing about **[Shaarli](https://shaarli.readthedocs.io/en/master/)**, a "personal, minimalist, super-fast, database free, bookmarking service". There is a link to a demo instance for you to try.

This is much more than a "browser extension", of course. It is a complete, **self-hosted** bookmarking app. There are "bookmarklets" provided, so it's easily integrated with any browser for easy/fast/simple bookmarking.

It doesn't look inspiring out-of-the-box (IMO):

[image: screenshot]

It is, however, fairly easily tweaked with custom CSS; I also run an instance using a nice (third-party, well maintained) ["Material" design](https://github.com/kalvn/Shaarli-Material).

I've used it for years, and now wouldn't be without it. You manage/own your own data, it is available on any platform, any device, and in any browser. Works a treat!